# Is there an allowed maximum number of AddTransient calls in .net Dependency Injection?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I am adding some modifications to an existing .Net-Core & Entity Framework-using webapp.
There is dependency injections used, and by now we have 22 lines of calling the AddTransient()-Method. Sadly I am the "chosen one", who is adding the 23rd call, and the webapp shows some strange behaviour. I debugged as deep as possible, and get stuck when I see a message: `Ein Ausnahmefehler des Typs "System.StackOverflowException" ist in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll aufgetreten.`

Translated to english something like: `An Exception of type "System.StackoverflowException" was raised in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll`

I am pretty sure the constructor of the 23rd class is built the same way as those 22 before. And if I disable another addTransient-Call, so there are 22 addTransient-calls again, the webapp works as is should. That's why I am assuming some limitation.

Did you encounter the same behaviour? Or are there some resources to read about limitations regarding Microsoft.Net Dependency Injection and what can be done in that case?

Comment: It's not transient call, but object initiated as part of 23rd call going into infinite recursion, leading to SO exception. You may shift that object to first number, it would still cause, check out that class, and rectify the issue

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I moved the 23rd addTransient to the position of the 1st one => webapp shows error. Then I commented out the 22nd addTransient-Call => webapp is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You very likely have a circular dependency.  Examine the new class you are trying to register and review its dependencies.  Better yet, remove all its dependencies temporarily and try again to register.

Comment: I commented out the addTransient-call for the 23rd class. Then I built a complete new class, and inserted the addTransient-call, to have a new "23rd". But the error still exists. If I reduce the calls to 22, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Due to some legal restrictions we cannot post the vital part of the source, and we neither do not have the time to rewrite it, to make it public available.

But we tried different things, and found out, changing the IoC-Container from Microsoft .net DI to Autofac had a positive impact, and the error went away.

I know, this will be no satisfying answer for all of you, but feel free to ask, if you want to know some specific details. But maybe it confirms your thoughts about giving Autofac (or any other IoC-Container) a chance.